# Append rows to a Google Sheet using drive.file scope

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Is it possible to append rows to an existing Google Sheet using `drive.file` scope?

The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope is defined as

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app

in the [Sheets docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) and

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File
>   authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the
>   user deauthorizes the app

in the [Drive docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).

What does Google mean by "opened" by the app? Open isn't a method in the API.

I've built an app that uses the `drive.file` scope, and the app authenticates and receives tokens just fine. When I try to append a row to an existing Sheet, the API response is a 404.

If I authenticate the same app using the more broad scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`, the app has no trouble appending rows to the same Sheet. I don't want to use a more broad scope that requires app verification because the app is an OAuth based plugin, a type of app [Google says should not require Sensitive or Restricted scopes or verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en). My app also fits the criteria Google recommends for the `drive.file` scope [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#select_scopes_for_a_new_app).

I have found all these questions that are near duplicates and have no definitive answers:

1. [Request specific file permissions with Google Sheets / Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967837/request-specific-file-permissions-with-google-sheets-google-drive-api)
2. [AuthToken for drive.file scope returning 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927953/authtoken-for-drive-file-scope-returning-404)
3. [Getting Google file picker to work with drive.file scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119557/getting-google-file-picker-to-work-with-drive-file-scope)
4. [How to use the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571487/how-to-use-the-scope-https-www-googleapis-com-auth-drive-file-correctly)
5. [Is there anyway to get private file of user with drive.file scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283307/is-there-anyway-to-get-private-file-of-user-with-drive-file-scope)
6. [Is the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file enough to create and update files or is the scope /drive needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344368/is-the-https-www-googleapis-com-auth-drive-file-enough-to-create-and-update-fi)

Comment: Basically, `drive.file` gives you access rights to the file you created with the app, not too any other files of the user. There is a good reason for the fact that you need to verify your app. After all the user should be aware that you have access to all of his spreadsheets.

Comment: I believe you're confusing OAuth authentication and Google app verification. The OAuth consent screen makes it clear to all users what access they are giving to the app.

Comment: I am sorry, if my comment was confusing. What I meant is that if you do not verify your app, the user will see an `Unverified app screen` which will warn him about potential dangers involved with certain scopes. Because without verification, there is no control about what your code is doing with the access to user's data.

Comment: I believe that is also incorrect. The unverified app screen is not shown when Recommended scopes are used. Only Sensitive and Restricted scopes trigger the unverified app screen, as explained by this link that is in my question: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Comment: Hi @rg89. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @jarora I wrote an answer to explain what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded no, it is not possible. I designed my app to have a "Create Sheet" button as a workaround, and the drive.file scope works fine to append rows and make other edits to a Sheet that my app creates.